# MySQL get multiple values from another table based on cells in current table

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for a bit of help with a query, I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
id, version, icon1id, icon2id, icon3id, icon4id, icon5id
1   1        1        2        3        2        3
2   1        2        3        4        3        2
3   1        3        4        3        4        2
4   1        4        5        2        2        1
```

Table 2:

```
id, version, iconid, iconname
1   1        1       red
2   1        2       blue
3   1        3       green
4   1        4       purple
5   1        5       yellow
6   2        1       red
7   2        2       purple
8   2        3       blue
9   2        4       yellow
10  2        5       green
```

I want to run a query on table 1 that displays something like the following:

```
id, version, icon1name, icon2name, icon3name, icon4name, icon5name
1   1        red        blue       green      blue       green
```

Basically, I am looking to write a query that uses the 'version' and 'iconid' in table 1 and returns the matching 'iconname' for each of them from table 2. I've spent some time searching for anything that would help but I'm struggling to adequately put into works what I'm trying to do to search properly...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) though technically what you need is a pivot query, which mysql doesn't support. the workarounds get very ugly, very fast, and can't handle arbitrary numbers of row->columns. do this in client-side code

Comment: Show us the query(s) that you have tried so far and tell us what is not working with them. So far you have not even asked a question.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods which doesn't handle arbitary numbers of row->columns :

2. Join

   select table1.id, table1.version, icon1.iconname, icon2.iconname from icons 
   left join table2 as icon1 on table1.version = icon1.version and table1.iconid1 = icon1.iconid 
   left join table2 as icon2 on table1.version = icon2.version and table1.iconid2 = icon2.iconid ...;
3. Select in select (ugly)

   select id, version, (select iconname from table2 where version = version and iconid = iconid1), (select iconname from table2 where version = version and iconid = iconid2), ... from table1;

Answer (score 0):

I am agreed with [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b). I also believe, that is the way, how it can be solved. Alternatively, you can just try the following query. You have to add an additional join for the additional columns.

```
select table1.id, table1.version, icon1.iconname, icon2.iconname, icon3.iconname from table1
left join
table2 icon1
on table1.version = icon1.version
and table1.icon1id = icon1.iconid 
left join
table2 icon2
on table1.version = icon2.version
and table1.icon2id = icon2.iconid 
left join
table2 icon3
on table1.version = icon3.version
and table1.icon3id = icon3.iconid 
order by table1.id
```